# html5's <video> not fading out with jquery in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

Javascript:

```
$("video").bind('ended', function(){
$("video").fadeOut(2000,function(){$("video").remove();});});​
```

HTML:

```
<video autobuffer controls autoplay>
<source id="mp4" src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

​CSS:

```
video {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
      }
```

In Firefox, as the video end's, it will fade. In Chrome, the only the controls fades, the video remains black, and when the fade is finished, vanish.
why doesn't it work in Chrome, but does in Firefox?(In Firefox I have tried the same video, but with .ogg format )

edit:
I change the video background to #ffffff, the fade seem to work backwards! 
It disappear, fades in ,  and disappear again. why?
​

Comment: have you thought about a different approach? like fading an layer in over the top and then removing that along with the video?

Comment: That wouldn't work with my site in particular .

Comment: I'm not talking about an overlay over the entire site, just the video element. That would work on almost any site... just make your overlay the same style as the background you're fading onto.

Comment: but I want the users to see the stuff below the video, won't it hide the content? (or have I misunderstood you?)

Answer (score 0):

What version of jquery are you using?

Using JQuery 1.8 (with chrome), in this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/velthune/HpHe7/2/) you can see that your code works!
Maybe your problem is somewhere else..

```
$("video").bind('ended', function(){
   console.log("video ended");
   $("video").fadeOut(2000,function(){
      $("video").remove();
   });
});​
```

## update

if your code still don't work in chrome, try to bind another event.

[This](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) is a good reference to take your test.

Comment: weird , your example doesn't work for me it only vanish after the 2 seconds. using ubuntu chrome Version 23.0.1271.64

Comment: The binding works, it does vanish after the delay time and the event is triggered. The problem is with the animation of the fade,it doesn't fade, just disappear

Answer (score 0):

Although the reason for the inconsistency between browsers is not clear for me, I were able to reproduce it and also to solve it by adding a parent div and fading the div.

So, html would be:

```
<div>
  <video autobuffer controls autoplay>
    <source id="mp4" src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Then, the JS would be:

```
$("video").bind('ended', function(){
    $("video").parent().fadeOut(2000,function(){
        $("video").remove();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Oops. Just realized how old this question is.